# URLSession cannot find 'self' in scope for errors and statusCode

Tags: swift, foundation, urlsession

My question is somewhat similar to [69959018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69959018/cannot-find-self-in-scope-swift), so I have made sure to clarify as much as I can

I'm trying to use the [Steam Web API](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API) to create an app that grabs everyone on my friend list in the form of a JSON dictionary. I'm trying to use foundation instead of Alamofire in order to learn Foundation better.

So far, what I've done is the following in AppDelegate.swift:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate { 
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        var apiKey: String = "[REDACTED]"
        var steamID: String = "[REDACTED]"
        let getPlayerSummaries = URL(string: "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=\(apiKey)&steamids=\(steamID)")
        
        let friendList = downloadPlayerSummaries(with: getPlayerSummaries) 
        print(friendList)
    }
func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    func applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState(_ app: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

In another file I made called networkManager.swift, I have wrote this based on what I have found in the apple documentation for "[Fetching Website Data into Memory](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/fetching_website_data_into_memory)" :

```
//
//  networkManager.swift
//  Who is online?
//
//  Created by Dash Interwebs on 11/21/21.
//

import Foundation


func downloadPlayerSummaries(with: URL!) {
    let url = with
    if url == nil {
        print("url is nil")
        return
    }
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
           if let error = error {
               self.handleClientError(error)
               return
           }
           guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
               (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
               self.handleServerError(response)
               return
           }
           
           }
       }
       task.resume()
}
```

After this however,  `self.handleClientError(error)`, and `self.handleServerError(response)` complain about being unable to find "self". I can't find anything about handleServerError or handleClientError. So where exactly is "self" in this context? I think that it might be URLSession but I'm not too sure.

Comment: `self` is not found because the code must be declared inside a class or struct. Unrelated but never ever declare a custom function parameter as implicit unwrapped optional (`!`). Remove the exclamation mark and the unnecessary check below. And `downloadPlayerSummaries` doesn't return anything. You are going to assign the function itself to the variable which makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your code using a completion handler and using an enum that conforms to the `Error` protocol:

enum ApiError: Error {
case network(Error)
case genericError
case httpResponseError
}

```
func downloadPlayerSummaries(with url: URL?, completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ error: ApiError?) -> Void) {
    guard let url = url else { return }
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            completion(false, .network(error))
            return
        }
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
              (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
                  completion(false, .httpResponseError)
                  return
              }

     // then handle your data. The completion should also include the kind of data your want to return 
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

I haven't tested. Let me know if it works.